# Selectors: Be specific on right-hand side?

Tags: jquery

[Learn jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/) says:

> Be specific on the right-hand side of your selector, and less specific
>   on the left.
>
> ```
> // Unoptimized:
> $( "div.data .gonzalez" );
>
> // Optimized:
> $( ".data td.gonzalez" );
> ```

I understand the part with the left-hand side, but what about the part to be specific on the right-hand size?  How true is this on modern browsers? As far as I'm aware, the Sizzle engine is not used on modern browsers. Let's modify our "unoptimized" example to this, to include the fact we need to be "specific" on the right-hand side by removing the `div`:

```
// Unoptimized modification:
$( ".data .gonzalez" );
```

For our "optimized" example we'd have (for modern browsers):

1. Have `queryselectorall` called on `.data`
2. Have `getElementsByTagName` on `td` from the result set from step 1.
3. Call `queryselectorall` for `.gonzales` from the result set from step 2

vs. our "unoptimized modification" example:

1. Have `queryselectorall` called on `.data`
2. Call `queryselectorall` for `.gonzales` from the result step from 1

Basically, we're skipping step 2. So won't:

```
$( ".data .gonzalez" );
```

run faster than:

```
$( ".data td.gonzalez" );
```

Making the principle "be specific on the right-hand size of your selector" obsolete for modern browsers?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is (much) faster than `querySelectorAll` for simple classes: https://jsperf.com/getelementsbyclassname-vs-queryselectorall/18

Comment: @CodeiSir Yes, but not that is the point. The question is why would you have to be specific on the right hand side? Why not simply drop the `td` selector.

Comment: @Cristy it's just a comment, not an answer ;) I wanted to add some Information, as it seemed to me that he did not know about the `getElementsByClassName` selector

Answer (score 0):

Using this HTML:

```
<div class="data">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="gonzalez">test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td class="gonzalez">test3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Firefox 43:**

`$("div.data .gonzalez");`, `$(".data td.gonzalez");` and `$(".data .gonzalez");` are equals (+/- 84866 operation / second).

**Chrome 47:**

`$(".data .gonzalez");` is the fastest one (+/- 166496 operation / second).

`$("div.data .gonzalez");` and `$(".data td.gonzalez");` are a bit slower (+/- 163243 operation / second).

**IE 11:**

`$(".data .gonzalez");` is the fastest one (+/- 55015 operation / second).

`$("div.data .gonzalez");` and `$(".data td.gonzalez");` are a bit slower (+/- 42490 operation / second)

**Opera 34:**

`$(".data .gonzalez");` and `$(".data td.gonzalez");` are the fastest (+/- 148887 operation / second).

`$("div.data .gonzalez");`  is a bit slower (+/- 135785 operation / second)

**Safari 5:**

`$("div.data .gonzalez");`, `$(".data td.gonzalez");` and `$(".data .gonzalez");` are equals (+/- 63560 operation / second).

I've created a test here: http://jsperf.com/compare-selector

Comment: The same test but with `querySelectorAll`: http://jsperf.com/compare-selector/2 - fun fact: it's much faster than jQuery :)

Comment: @CodeiSir Chrome 47 and these results are not very different. Is this how the parser works in the background (going LEFT from RIGHT) as opposed from right to left with the Sizzle engine?